# PHP Slim framework ErrorHandler - send exception to client

Tags: slim

I implemented ErrorHandler in my Slim Framework REST API:

```
$container['errorHandler'] = function ($c) {
    return function (ServerRequestInterface $request, Response $response, $exception) use ($c) {
        $data = [
            'message' => $exception->getMessage()
        ];
        return $c->get('response')->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->write(json_encode($data));
    };
};
```

I try to create error:

```
    public function test(ServerRequestInterface $request, Response $response){
        $email = null;
        $arr = [1,2];
        $x = $arr[3]; //Undefined array key 3
    }
```

I see the error in the Postman correctly (Status 500, {message: Undefined array key 3}, but in Developer tools in browser (Response tab) is only "Failed to load response data: No data found for resource with gived identifier".
In JS is this error:

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://localhost:8080/auth/login","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/auth/login: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

When I send error response from test method:

```
public function test(ServerRequestInterface $request, Response $response){
        return $response->withStatus(500)
            ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->write("ERROR");
    }
```

in JS is correct exception object, and I see response in Developer tools:

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null},"status":500,"statusText":"Internal Server Error","url":"http://localhost:8080/auth/login","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/auth/login: 500 Internal Server Error","error":"ERROR"}
```

what could be the problem? How to send error from errorHandler correctly?
Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0):

The PSR-7 headers are immutable, but the HTTP body methods are not immutable.

To fix it try this:

```php
$response = $response
    ->withStatus(500)
    ->withHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    
$response->getBody()->write(json_encode($data)));

return $response;
```

Comment: This is not working, still same problem